# How to show that $SO_{2,1}^+$ is path connected?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, path-connected, linear-groups

I need to show that $SO_{2,1}^+$ is path connected.

First of all here are a couple of definitions we are using in the lecture:

Let $n=r+s$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$I_{r,s} := diag(\underbrace{ 1,\ldots,1}_{\text{$r$ times}},\underbrace{ -1,\ldots,-1}_{\text{$s$ times}})$$
$$O_{r,s} := \{M \in M_n \mid M^TI_{r,s}M = I_{r,s} \}$$
$$SO_{r,s} := \{M \in M_n \mid M^TI_{r,s}M = I_{r,s} \text{ and } det(M) = 1 \}$$
$$SO_{r,s}^+ := \{M \in M_n \mid M \in SO_{r,s} \text{ and } z > 0 \text{ for } (x,y,z)^T: = M\cdot(0,0,1)^T \}$$

Remark: Everything here is over $\mathbb{R}$.

I have already seen in the lecture that $SO_2$ is path-connected, but I do not understand how I should prove this for $SO_{r,s}^+$. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Finally, the last definition is written for $r=2$ and $s=1$, no? Did you mean to simply say that the $(n,n)$ entry in $M$ is positive? Or is it something different for general $r,s$?

Comment: I made another edit:)